# rvmsudo does not work in deploy.rb on ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, capistrano

The following is the error running cap deploy. The problem is that rvmsudo was not found.

```
 * executing "cd /vol/www/emclab/current && rvmsudo /home/dtt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/bundle install vendor/gems"
    servers: ["12.34.56.78"]
    [12.34.56.78] executing command
*** [err :: 12.34.56.78] sh: rvmsudo: not found
```

However the same command "rvmsudo /home/dtt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/bundle install vendor/gems" was running manually on remote server successfully. But why the same command does not work in 'cap deploy'?

Thanks.

Here is the deploy.rb:

```
set :application, "myapp"
set :repository,  "git://github.com/myapp/myapp.git"
set :scm, :git
set :user, "dtt"
set :use_sudo, true
set :scm_passphrase, "phrase"
set :branch, "master"
set :deploy_to, "/vol/www/#{application}"
#set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `git`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, `subversion` or `none`

server "12.34.56.78", :web, :app, :db, :primary => true
#role :web, "your web-server here"                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
#role :app, "your app-server here"                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
#role :db,  "your primary db-server here", :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run
#role :db,  "your slave db-server here"

# if you're still using the script/reaper helper you will need
# these http://github.com/rails/irs_process_scripts

after "deploy", "deploy:bundle_gems"
after "deploy:bundle_gems", "deploy:restart"
# If you are using Passenger mod_rails uncomment this:
 namespace :deploy do
   task :bundle_gems do
     run "cd #{deploy_to}/current && /home/dtt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/bundle install vendor/gems"
   end
   task :start do ; end
   task :stop do ; end
   task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
     run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe Capistrano doesn't use a login shell, so the line in .bash_profile that loads RVM is never executed.

What version of RVM are you using? If you're using < 1.5, RVM implode and reinstall.
If you're using >= 1.5, try adding the following to your deploy.rb:

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'

$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))
require 'rvm/capistrano'
set :rvm_ruby_string, '1.9.2'

set :rvm_bin_path, "/usr/local/bin"
```

Adjust the :rvm_bin_path to wherever your rvm executable is.

Comment: Is the block in above answer added to Set section of the deploy.rb? Also do I need to keep the 'task :bundle_gems do' as it was?

Comment: added the code block above and execute cap deploy, here is the error: C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': no such file to load -- rvm/capistrano (LoadError)